# Why does String(value).replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '') work?

Tags: javascript

I saw `String(value).replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '')` from a library that described to filter illegal characters, and finally it will return the legal number. Why does this work and what will really be replaced? I feel confused because I think nothing will be replaced.

For example:

```
String("1.absd").replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '')
// '1.'
```

Comment: It is RegEx that removes anything other than number 0-9 and .(Period).

Comment: Why do you think nothing will be replaced? That pattern doesn't match nothing: https://regex101.com/r/arivF4/1.

Comment: It does match 4 characters `absd` that are not in range of 0-9 and also not .(period) or -(minus). You can see in top right, it says `4 matches`.

Comment: It's notable, that `replace` returns a new string, it doesn't replace in-place (strings are immutable), that way it might look like nothing has been replaced.

Comment: i mix the "^" symbol, i think it means "the start", but it actually means "not, except".I got it now!thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. `String(value)` will make string from value. So if you use number, this will convert it to string, because function replace is defined only from string.
2. `replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '')` this will replace any matching given regular expression with empty string. In regular expression you have [^0-9.-]. The ^ at start means, that any characters not from this interval will match. So any character other than number, dot or -. Modifier g after slash means, that this regular expression is global and will be applied for all matches

so from "1.absd" the characters "absd" will be replaced with empty string

Comment: The `g` means "global", not greedy - the term greedy is usually used to describe quantifiers like `+` and is modified with `?`

Comment: @SpoonMeiser `+` has nothing to do with greediness. It’s a quantifier that says “at least one” and is equivalent to the quantifier `{1,}`. `?` (after the quantifier) is the non-greedy (or “lazy”) _qualifier_. A pattern is greedy by default without this qualifier.

Comment: @SebastianSimon yes - my point was that this is what the term "greedy" usually refers to. The `g` in `/.../g` isn't called "greedy", because then you're using the same word to mean two different things which is confusing - my suggestion to improve this answer is to use the word "global" instead, which is how it's usually referred to.